# terminal Vim strikethrough

Tags: vim, configuration, neovim, text-rendering

I'm trying to render strikethrough for markdown files in terminal vim. However, with the current plug-ins and colorscheme it either colors the text or underlines it. I'm nit-picky and I'd like the rendering of strikethrough.

Running `:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim` in a markdown file rightly shows the highlights including the underline/coloring, but also the `groupname` which is `htmlStrike`.

So I try adding the following to my `init.vim`(having read `:h attr-list`):

```
function s:ApplyStrikethrough()
    highlight htmlStrike cterm=strikethrough 
endfunction
autocmd FileType md call s:ApplyStrikethrough()
```

I've also tried the above without the autocmd, e.g. just `highlight htmlStrike cterm=strikethrough`. I've also tried `highlight htmlStrike gui=strikethrough guisp='Red'`. All I can accomplish is having no highlight at all...

I know my terminal (Kitty) is capable of rendering strikethrough, having run `echo -e "\e[9mstrikethrough\e[0m"`.

```
OS:    Manjaro Linux x86_64
WM:    i3
shell: zsh 5.7.1
Vim:   NVIM v0.4.3
Term:  kitty 0.15.1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What terminal type are you using?  At the shell, type `echo $TERM`.

Comment: @bk2204 is on the right path, you may need to set some attributes for your terminfo

Comment: Thank you both for your time! It returns ```xterm-kitty```.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem, and found a solution for normal vim after a while of researching.

I have put the following in my `.vimrc`

```
if &term =~ 'xterm\|kitty\|alacritty\|tmux'
    let &t_Ts = "\e[9m"   " Strikethrough
    let &t_Te = "\e[29m"
    let &t_Cs = "\e[4:3m" " Undercurl
    let &t_Ce = "\e[4:0m"
endif
```

This will enable strikethrough and undercurl for xterm, kitty, alacritty and tmux terminals (identified by the `TERM` environment variable). Ideally the if-test should perhaps rely on the `smxx`, `rmxx` (standard) and `So` (kitty extension) capabilities from the terminfo database, but I don't know how to query it from a vim script.

This can be tested by for instance formatting the status line, or with the highlight group `htmlStrike` as in the question.

```
:hi StatusLine cterm=strikethrough`.
```

The trick for undercurl is mentioned in `:help undercurl`. `:help terminal-output-codes` lists the terminal codes vim knows about, which also reveals strikethrough. Note that the escape code for strikethrough is defined in [ECMA-48](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-48/) (called "Crossed-out"), while undercurl is defined by Kitty in its [protocol extensions](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty/blob/518e0f4e2139ac7d9cd2ec81c9d09ecbeee4bf3c/docs/underlines.rst).

A quick note on neovim: For me, strikethrough worked out of the box with neovim, but undercurl fell back to normal underline. I have not investigated this beyond noting that neovim does not have the `terminal-output-codes` help topic.